# Statement is true for all continuous functions with compact support, then it must also be true in $L^{1}(G)$ by density?

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, functions, locally-compact-groups

I'm reading a proof about the existence of a left invariant mean on certain types of groups, and I came across this part that I don't quite understand:

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group.

We have that $m_{\varphi}(f)=\int_{G}f \hspace{0.1cm}d\mu$ for any continuous function $f:G \to \mathbb{C}$ with compact support. (This is shown in the proof but I don't think the details are necessary here)

Then as the set of continuous functions with compact support is dense in $L^{1}(G)$ we have  $m_{\varphi}(f)=\int_{G}f \hspace{0.1cm}d\mu$ for all $f \in L^{1}(G)$

What I don't quite understand is why the density of the compact support functions automatically extends the statement to the whole of $L^{1}(G)$. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain this!

Comment: Do you know that $m_\varphi\in  L^1(G)^\star$?

Comment: The answer depends on what $m_{\phi}$ stands for. Some property of this function is needed.

Comment: This is "automatic" only if you already know that the set of functions for which the statement holds is a closed set in $L^1$.  Such a statement is sometimes called a "closed condition".  With experience you can often tell by inspection when this is the case, so advanced books and research papers may not explain the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what $m_\varphi$ is, but assuming that it is a continuous function from $L^1(G)$ into $\mathbb C$ then whoever wrote that is using that fact that if two continuous functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from a topological space $X$ into a topological space $Y$ are such that, for some dense subset $D$ of $X$,$$(\forall x\in D):\alpha(x)=\beta(x),$$then $\alpha=\beta$. This is so because the set $\{x\in X\mid\alpha(x)=\beta(x)\}$ is a closed subset of $X$ and, since $D$ is dense in $X$, the only closed subset of $X$ containing $D$ is $X$ itself.

Comment: Fixed a small typo for you! The interpretation was a bit different with it. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Of course not. It was nice of you.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of a book where I could find this result?

Comment: Any introduction to Topology contais this. But why do you want such a book? I provided a proof, right?!